# Entity Framework and multiple schemas

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm trying to set up my dbContext so that it can handle multiple schemas in a single Oracle database. I didn't want one monolithic dbContext file so I've come up with the following:

```
public class oraDbContext : DbContext
{
    static oraDbContext() {
        Database.SetInitializer<oraDbContext>(null);
    }

    public oraDbContext(string connName)
        : base("Name=" + connName) { }

    public _schema1 schema1 = _schema1.Instance;
    public _schema2 schema2 = _schema2.Instance;

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        schema1.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        schema2.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

The schema file looks like this:

```
public sealed class _schema1
{
    private static readonly _schema1 instance = new _schema1();

    static _schema1() { }
    private _schema1() { }

    public static _schema1 Instance {
        get {
            return instance;
        }
    }

    public DbSet<someTable> someTable { get; set; }

    internal void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new someTableMap());
    }
}
```

However, when I try to perform a query I get the error: `Value cannot be null`. The value it's referring to is the `someTable` property in _schema1.

**A.** How can I fix this?

**B.** Is there a better solution?

**Edit:** What I want here is the ability to write code such as the following -

```
var query1 = from p in db.schema1.someTable
             select p;
var query2 = from p in db.schema2.someTable
             select p;
```

Where someTable is the same in both schemas. In our database we have several schemas with the exact same tables that have identical or nearly identical columns. I don't want to create a seperate dbContext for each schema because that could potentially mean 5 different connections if I'm creating a query that pulls from 5 schemas. If I was writing this same query in straight SQL I could pull the data from 5 different schemas with a single connection and that's what I would like to accomplish here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

While doing some research about Entity Framework I came across the following post:

http://romiller.com/2011/05/23/ef-4-1-multi-tenant-with-code-first/

It doesn't quite give me a single dbContext to work with but it does only use a single connection (which was my reasoning behind not wanting to use multiple dbContexts). After setting up the following code:

```
public class oraDbContext : DbContext
{
    static oraDbContext() {
        Database.SetInitializer<oraDbContext>(null);
    }

    private oraDbContext(DbConnection connection, DbCompiledModel model)
        : base(connection, model, contextOwnsConnection: false) { }

    public DbSet<SomeTable1> SomeTable1 { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SomeTable2> SomeTable2 { get; set; }

    private static ConcurrentDictionary<Tuple<string, string>, DbCompiledModel> modelCache = new ConcurrentDictionary<Tuple<string, string>, DbCompiledModel>();

    public static oraDbContext Create(string schemaName, DbConnection connection) {
        var compiledModel = modelCache.GetOrAdd(
            Tuple.Create(connection.ConnectionString, schemaName),
            t =>
            {
                var builder = new DbModelBuilder();
                builder.Configurations.Add<SomeTable1>(new SomeTable1Map(schemaName));
                builder.Configurations.Add<SomeTable2>(new SomeTable2Map(schemaName));

                var model = builder.Build(connection);
                return model.Compile();
            });

        return new oraDbContext(connection, compiledModel);
    }
}
```

This of course requires that my mapping files be set up like so:

```
public class DailyDependencyTableMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<DailyDependencyTable>
{
    public SomeTableMap(string schemaName) {
        this.ToTable("SOME_TABLE_1", schemaName.ToUpper());

        //Map other properties and stuff
    }
}
```

Writing queries that use multiple schemas is somewhat annoying but, for the moment, it does what I need it to do:

```
using (var connection = new OracleConnection("a connection string")) {
    using (var schema1 = oraDbContext.Create("SCHEMA1", connection))
    using (var schema2 = oraDbContext.Create("SCHEMA2", connection)) {

        var query = ((from a in schema1.SomeTable1 select new { a.Field1 }).ToList())
             .Concat((from b in schema2.SomeTable1 select new { b.Field1 }).ToList())
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for using GetOrAdd() to condense code in a readable fashion. Would just like to underline the fact that using .ToList() to merge results in the two components of the query is crucial since we are trying to combine queries from different contexts (<- with entity framework and probably other orms as well, such operations cannot be applied directly on the database).

Answer (score 9):

You can specify schema per table via `Table` attribute.

```
[Table(nameof(MyTable1), Schema = "Schema1")]
public class MyTable1 { }

[Table(nameof(MyTable2), Schema = "Schema2")]
public class MyTable2 { }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using partial classes instead

```
public partial class oraDbContext : DbContext
{
    static oraDbContext() {
        Database.SetInitializer<oraDbContext>(null);
    }

    public oraDbContext(string connName)
        : base("Name=" + connName) { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        schema1(modelBuilder);
        schema2(modelBuilder);
    }
}

public partial class oraDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<someTable> someTable { get; set; }
    void schema1(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new someTableMap());
    }
}
```

Comment: I finally got a chance to test this today and I get an error: `oraDbContext already contains a definition for 'someTable'`. Edited question to better reflect what I'm looking for.