# Can we use application variables in edmx XML file

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, schema, edmx

there is a schema tag in edmx XML file defined for each entity being used in edmx ...

```
<EntitySet Name="AUDITLOG" EntityType="My_EFModel.Store.AUDITLOG" store:Type="Tables" Schema="MYPRODUCTUSER" />
```

is there any way i can set this Schema Attribute through my application's variable ... 
Are my application's variable public to this edmx XML file.? ...

i would like to change this as follows so that schema attribute becomes configurable:

```
<EntitySet Name="AUDITLOG" EntityType="My_EFModel.Store.AUDITLOG" store:Type="Tables" Schema="@MyProject'sApplication'sVariable" />
```

The problem is that we work on a product database, and another team takes our Database (say A) and creates their seperate database (Say B), 
The two databases are exact copy of each other that is why i want Schema attribute to be configurable ...

Comment: I'd say no, as far as I know isn't the same table in two different schemas considered a different table, also this file is processed at build time not run time. Could you clarify the end goal and maybe someone will offer a different solution.

Comment: @matt_lethargic
Yes, added explaination, please re read the Question.

Comment: So you just want to change the connection string and point at database B?! The schema would stay the same surely

Comment: @matt_lethargic no .... its name is different .. , for team X : Schema="MyProductUser"
and for Team Y: Schema = "SomeOtherUser"

Comment: @matt_lethargic ... this is the reason Schema attribute should be configurable in this case ... is'nt it?

Comment: the database are same BUT their Schema name , Connection strings are kept different

Comment: Have to tried searching for way to change schema in code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14902245/entity-framework-and-multiple-schemas