# Separate database for every users in application in mvc5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database-design, asp.net-mvc-5, multi-tenant

I have application which stores all the user specific information in one database. But, I want to make user specific database. For instance, when user register in application then it should create database for that particular user with the same schema, which i currently have in database. Guide me if there is any solution for it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Entity Framework and multiple schemas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14902245/entity-framework-and-multiple-schemas)

Comment: The use case does not call for going for multitenant architecture Seperate DB. Have you done enough analysis on why you should even consider Seperated DB? What solution are you expecting from SO users?

Comment: Whu do you want such a thing?